# Thread.join() caused Component update froze

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a question regarding multi-threading.

Basically I have this method:

```
public void instructs(Pacman pacman) {
    Iterator it = q.iterator();
    Thread t = null;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        try {
            String function = q.remove();
            if (t != null) t.join();
            MovementUpdater mu = new MovementUpdater(pacman, function);
            t = new Thread(mu);
            t.start();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

The `MovementUpdater` class is a Runnable that contains implementations for `function` (eg: turn-left, turn-right). So if I have only 1 function defines, the Thread `t` works fine. What I meant by fine is the `pacman` (JLabel) was able to update its Icon.

The problem is when I have more than 1 `function`, the Icon of `pacman` only updated from the last Thread. `t.join()` seems made my `pacman` not updated (changing its Icon) in real-time.

So, any idea to solve this - to ensure the Icon of `pacman` updated properly in real time in each Thread?

```
package com.stiw5024.project.edugame.jpacman.engine.animation;

import com.stiw5024.project.edugame.jpacman.constants.BoardConstants;
import com.stiw5024.project.edugame.jpacman.constants.FacingConstants;
import com.stiw5024.project.edugame.jpacman.constants.MovementConstants;
import com.stiw5024.project.edugame.jpacman.engine.Pacman;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MovementUpdater implements Runnable {

    private final Pacman pacman;
    private final String function;

    public MovementUpdater(Pacman pacman, String function) {
        this.pacman = pacman;
        this.function = function;
    }

    private void updateFacing(String previousFacing, String func) {
        switch (previousFacing) {
            case FacingConstants.FACE_UP: // 0 degree
                switch (func) {
                    case MovementConstants.TURN_LEFT:
                        pacman.setFacing(FacingConstants.FACE_LEFT);
                        break;
                    case MovementConstants.TURN_RIGHT:
                        pacman.setFacing(FacingConstants.FACE_RIGHT);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case FacingConstants.FACE_DOWN: // 180 degrees
                switch (func) {
                    case MovementConstants.TURN_LEFT:
                        pacman.setFacing(FacingConstants.FACE_RIGHT);
                        break;
                    case MovementConstants.TURN_RIGHT:
                        pacman.setFacing(FacingConstants.FACE_LEFT);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case FacingConstants.FACE_RIGHT: // 90 degrees
                switch (func) {
                    case MovementConstants.TURN_LEFT:
                        pacman.setFacing(FacingConstants.FACE_UP);
                        break;
                    case MovementConstants.TURN_RIGHT:
                        pacman.setFacing(FacingConstants.FACE_DOWN);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case FacingConstants.FACE_LEFT: // 270 degrees
                switch (func) {
                    case MovementConstants.TURN_LEFT:
                        pacman.setFacing(FacingConstants.FACE_DOWN);
                        break;
                    case MovementConstants.TURN_RIGHT:
                        pacman.setFacing(FacingConstants.FACE_UP);
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int angle = 0;
        int lastAngle;
        switch (pacman.getFacing()) {
            case FacingConstants.FACE_UP:
                if (function.equals(MovementConstants.TURN_LEFT)) {
                    angle = 360;
                }
                break;
            case FacingConstants.FACE_DOWN:
                angle = 180;
                break;
            case FacingConstants.FACE_LEFT:
                angle = 270;
                break;
            case FacingConstants.FACE_RIGHT:
                angle = 90;
                break;
        }

        try {
            switch (function) {
                case MovementConstants.TURN_LEFT:
                    lastAngle = angle - 90;
                    for (int a = angle; a >= lastAngle; a -= 5) {
                        final int currentAngle = a;
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (currentAngle == 360) {
                                    pacman.setIcon(BoardConstants.PACMAN[0]);
                                } else {
                                    pacman.setIcon(BoardConstants.PACMAN[currentAngle]);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        Thread.sleep(20);
                    }
                    break;
                case MovementConstants.TURN_RIGHT:
                    lastAngle = angle + 90;
                    for (int a = angle; a <= lastAngle; a += 5) {
                        final int currentAngle = a;
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (currentAngle == 360) {
                                    pacman.setIcon(BoardConstants.PACMAN[0]);
                                } else {
                                    pacman.setIcon(BoardConstants.PACMAN[currentAngle]);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        Thread.sleep(20);
                    }
                    break;
                case MovementConstants.ADVANCE:
                    break;
                case MovementConstants.CLIMB_UP:
                    break;
                case MovementConstants.EAT:
                    break;
            }
            updateFacing(pacman.getFacing(), function);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't you know what `join` is for?

Comment: All i know join() is like if you want to make Thread runs in sequence. Sorry, if I am wrong, I am still new to multithreading concept

Comment: That is exactly what your code is doing, executing your movements in sequence (provided that your threads terminate in some way - if not `join` blocks).

Comment: Sorry, I maybe put some misleaded statement in the question. What I meant by blocking the previous Thread is like it's frozing the my `pacman` to update its Icon.

Comment: Why use a different thread if you're just going to join the threads? You need to read up on how to use threads it seems.

Comment: Yes, your `instructs` is probably called under the control of the event dispatcher thread (event handling function) and blocking it is a very bad bad idea.

Comment: Ok, if I am not to use Thread, what do you suggest to improve my design in updating my `pacman` Icon based on `function` iterated? I think you need to see my `MovementUpdater` class.

Comment: Ok, updated my question!